# A tabela 'VW_XXXXX' não foi localizada. A tabela não foi localizada

Tags: crystal-reports

Boa tarde!

Peço o apoio de vocês, estou com um problema estranho. Criei uma view em um determinado owner e uso está view em um crystal reports. Com o meu usuário (seto os valores no App.Config da minha solução, que aliás é em c#) eu consigo gerar os relatórios sem problema, porém, com o usuário da aplicação não rola. Eu solicitei a grant de leitura ao usuário da aplicação nas tabela dentro da view e na própria view.... Se eu executo a consulta pelo PLSQL com o usuário da aplicação ele retorna informação normal, mas se executo através do crystal gera o seguinte erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nota: Pessoal, como falei, com meu user funcional normalmente, mas o erro ocorre somente com o user da aplicação. Acredito ter solicitado o grant correto.

Obrigado!

Comment: Tentou com owner.view no Crystal ou criar um sinonimo público para a view ?

Comment: Bom dia, Motta.
Na verdade sim. Pedi um sinonima desta view aos dba's. Estou suspeitando da versão do crystal. Este é um "rpt" legado de um VB que estou automatizando no c#, logo talvez haja um problema de versionamento visto que ele deve ter sido feito na versão 9 e estou usando a 11. Vou ver isto (me toquei disto ontem) e posto aqui... Mas se tiver outra ideia, por favor... :D